How to match fields sub_category_id in database with SubCategory in excel data when importing data excel to laravel?
I want to import excel data to laravel database, but in my database i have sub_category_id fields that refer to my sub_categories table, in my excel template the sub_category_id named SubCategory, the SubCategory in my excel template is string, but my sub_category_id is int, how to match that?
this is my Import file :
public function model(array $row)
{
    $qrCode = $this->generateQrCode($row);

    return new FixedAsset([
        'sub_category_id'      => $row[1],
        'specific_location_id' => $row[2],
        'procurement_id'       => $row[3],
        'unit_id'              => $row[4],
        'user_id'              => $row[5],
        'tahun_perolehan'      => $row[6],
        'kode_bmn'             => $row[7],
        'kode_sn'              => $row[8],
        'kondisi'              => $row[9],
        'image'                => $row[10],
        'harga'                => $row[11],
        'keterangan'           => $row[12],
    ]);
}

this is my import data function in controller
public function import(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $namaFile = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = public_path('/storage/AssetExcel/' . $namaFile);
    $file->move('storage/AssetExcel', $namaFile);

    try {
        Excel::import(new AssetImport(), $path);

        return redirect()->back()->with(
            'success',
            'Data berhasil diimpor.'
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->back()->with(
            'error',
            'Terjadi kesalahan saat mengimpor data: ' . $e->getMessage()
        );
    }
}

this is my excel template



No
SubCategory
Lokasi
Mitra
Satuan
Pj
tahun_perolehan
kode_bmn
kode_sn
kondisi
image
harga
keterangan




1
Acer Nitro 5
TIK
XL
Unit
Bill

111111111
SN123456789
Baik
tes.png
2000000
Baik




You could build a subcategory map in your import when it's created and then use it in your model function.
protected $subcategories;

public function __construct(...)
{
    $this->subcategories = Subcategory::pluck('id', 'name');
}

public function model(array $row)
{
    $qrCode = $this->generateQrCode($row);

    return new FixedAsset([
        'sub_category_id'      => $this->subcategories->get($row[1]),
        'specific_location_id' => $row[2],
        'procurement_id'       => $row[3],
        'unit_id'              => $row[4],
        'user_id'              => $row[5],
        'tahun_perolehan'      => $row[6],
        'kode_bmn'             => $row[7],
        'kode_sn'              => $row[8],
        'kondisi'              => $row[9],
        'image'                => $row[10],
        'harga'                => $row[11],
        'keterangan'           => $row[12],
    ]);
}

Or make a query on each row
public function model(array $row)
{
    $qrCode = $this->generateQrCode($row);

    return new FixedAsset([
        'sub_category_id'      => SubCategory::where('name', $row[1])->first()->id,
        'specific_location_id' => $row[2],
        'procurement_id'       => $row[3],
        'unit_id'              => $row[4],
        'user_id'              => $row[5],
        'tahun_perolehan'      => $row[6],
        'kode_bmn'             => $row[7],
        'kode_sn'              => $row[8],
        'kondisi'              => $row[9],
        'image'                => $row[10],
        'harga'                => $row[11],
        'keterangan'           => $row[12],
    ]);
}

